# how to set the div's width is Exactly the width of the word in it 

Tags: javascript, jquery, width

this is the demo :http://jsfiddle.net/KwYjr/10/

how to set the blue div's width is Exactly the width of the word

thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

css:

```
display:inline;
```

Comment: You could also use `display: inline-block` if things don't play that well. +1 for good answer.

Answer (score 1):

Consider using `<span>`. they have no formatting of their own and so should help you wrap or whatever you're trying.

EDIT : span's are the best/default way to do "inline" stuff. div's are by default block elements.

Answer (score 1):

setting the div to display inline will make the div the exact width:

```
display: inline;
```

however, from trying this out on your sample the draggable panel then goes left and right. if you still want to maintain the same up down motion you should wrap it in another div and then put the inline div inside it like:

```
<div id="a" style="position:absolute;width:200px;height:200px;background:red;word-wrap:break-word;">
    <div id="b"><div style="background:blue; display: inline;">sssssssss</div></div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

I updated your Fiddle to demonstrate the answers.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know how to get the width of a word, but what you can do is set a fixed sized for letters, which will easily get you the width of every letter which then gives you the width of the words. Then, measure the div's width with Javascript:

```
document.getElementById("thediv").style.width;
```

Is that what you meant to do?

Answer (score 0):

Set width to auto

http://jsfiddle.net/ozzy/KwYjr/24/

or

http://jsfiddle.net/ozzy/KwYjr/25/